# Visualforce | Multi Conditional Block Rendering

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

I have a beginner's question..

I'm trying to make a VF PageBlOckSection render by the following logic:

---

IF Opportunity.Cancellation__c == TRUE AND Opportunity.Paid_Upfront__c == TRUE than Render 2 fields (Amount and Expiry Date)

IF Opportunity.Cancellation__c == TRUE AND Opportunity.Paid_Upfront__c == FALSE than Render 1 fields (Expiry Date)

IF Opportunity.Cancellation__c == FALSE AND Opportunity.Paid_Upfront__c == TRUE than Render 2 fields (Amount and Expiry Date)

IF Opportunity.Cancellation__c == FALSE AND Opportunity.Paid_Upfront__c == FALSE than do not render.

---

However I cannot make it work by the desired logic... I'm using this code: 
I'll appreciate any advice!

Thanks,
Jonathan

---

```
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Please fill the Expiry Date & Upfront Amount" columns="1" rendered="{!IF(AND(!Opportunity.Paid_Upfront__c == TRUE, !Opportunity.Cancellation__c != TRUE), TRUE, FALSE)}">

            <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Subscription_Expiry_Date__c}"/>
             <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Amount}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>


        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Please fill the Expiry Date" columns="1" rendered="{!IF(AND(!Opportunity.Paid_Upfront__c == FALSE, !Opportunity.Cancellation__c != TRUE), TRUE, FALSE)}">

            <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Subscription_Expiry_Date__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>


        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Please fill the Expiry Date" columns="1" rendered="{!IF(AND(!Opportunity.Paid_Upfront__c == TRUE, !Opportunity.Cancellation__c == TRUE), TRUE, FALSE)}">

            <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Subscription_Expiry_Date__c}"/>
             <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Amount}"/>

        </apex:pageBlockSection>


    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you are in a Visualforce `{! }` expression fields are referenced without a further `!` (and a `!` prefix becomes shorthand for a `NOT` function). Also the result of the `AND` function is already a boolean so the surrounding `IF` is not needed.

So for "paid upfront and cancellation" and "not paid upfront and not cancellation" the expressions can be:

```
rendered="{! AND(Opportunity.Paid_Upfront__c, Opportunity.Cancellation__c) }"
rendered="{! AND(NOT(Opportunity.Paid_Upfront__c), NOT(Opportunity.Cancellation__c)) }"
```

If you prefer operators over functions, this equivalent form also normally works:

```
rendered="{! Opportunity.Paid_Upfront__c && Opportunity.Cancellation__c }"
rendered="{! !Opportunity.Paid_Upfront__c && !Opportunity.Cancellation__c }"
```